# Create a pivot table with difference between 2 datetime columns as a timespan showing millisecond

Tags: excel, datetime, pivot-table, milliseconds, calculation

Im new to pivot tables. I have a table of data from a database that has 2 datetime columns (datetime2 sql type). I would like to create a pivot table from the database table. For each row I would like to show a calculated column that shows the difference between the 2 datetime(s) and displays it as a timespan in milliseconds.

Comment: Add that calculation to the database as an additional column. Then it will be a field you can show in the pivot table.

Comment: I can't modify the database. Can I instead create a calculated field in the pivot table, and go from there? Like create calculation per row as time span. Then show the timespan value as millisecond. I just don't see how to do that with a pivot chart.